# Need to convert Mongo string field to array of Object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6228cd8e72e74fa2a4bbd76c"),
    "userId" : 8426,
    "answer" : "https://cdn.upgrad.com/resumejyotiranjana.docx",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-09T13:48:17.296Z"),
    "questionIdentifier" : "resumeLink",
}
```

I need to convert answer into array of objects, The existing answer will become resumeLink properties and updatedAT will become dateUploaded in object.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6228cd8e72e74fa2a4bbd76c"),
    "userId" : 8426,
    "answer" : [
                 {
                    "resumeLink":"https://cdn.upgrad.com/resume/asasjyotiranjana11.docx",
                    "dateUploaded": "2022-06-09T13:48:17.296Z",
                    "resumeId": "7fa1478d-478f-4869-9c4b-7ca8c0b9434g",
                    "source": "hiration"
                 }
                ],
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-09T13:48:17.296Z"),
    "questionIdentifier" : "resumeLink",
}
```

Whats the quick way to achieve this with mongo query? thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you get the other fields (`resumeId`, `source`) values? Can you post your schema declaration?

Comment: resumeId will be any random UUID, source will have always default value hiration

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation query as below.
You may need to add some fields in that.

```
const agg = [
  {
    '$match': {
      'userId': 8426
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$userId', 
      'answers': {
        '$addToSet': {
          'recordId': '$_id', 
          'resumeLink': '$answer'
        }
      }
    }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Below mongo query worked:

```
db.getCollection('userfeedback').updateMany(
    {userId:8426, questionIdentifier:"resumeLink"},
    [{
        "$set": {
                    answer: [{  
                              "resumeLink": "$answer",
                              "resumeId": UUID().hex().match(/^(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})$/).slice(1,6).join('-'),
                              "uploadSizeInByte": -1,
                              "source":"manual",
                              "dateUploaded": "$updatedAt"
                              }]
            }
    }]
)
```

Comment: You didn't mention that you want to do update query.
You just mention word "query".